# How to update/Order 'Android.mk' file?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, native

I started working on an 'Android Studio' project which was imported from Eclipse. In this project I have two .c files that makes me lot of problems:

D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\ip\ip.c
D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\nativeinterface\native.c

I'm updeting the code of this files, and every few compilations (Build ---> Build Project) I'm getting the following error:

"This file is not part of the project. Please include it in the appropriate build file (build.gradle, CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk etc.) and sync the project"

I try to perform Build ---> "Refresh Linked C++ Projects", sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, and if it works, a few compilations later the error returns.

I think that the problem related to the file:

D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\Android.mk

which you can see below. I have 5 main questions about it:

1. I see in this file some *.mk, *.mk.swp, and *.so files, is that OK? should this files be there?
2. In my files pathes I have this slash '\', but in some example in the internet I see this slash '/', which one is the right one? does it matter at all?
3. I can see two main sections in this file:

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES`

`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`

Should I add the pathes to the "ip.c" and "native.c" files in both sections? or only to one of them?

4. In the project I see more 'Android.mk' files (which are shorter) should they be there also aditional to the main 'Android.mk' file?

For example this is the 'Android.mk' in the folder of 'ip.c' file:

---

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
     ip.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE := ipAndroidApp

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

and this is the 'Android.mk' in the folder of 'native.c' file:

---

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
LOCAL_MODULE    := native

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

---

5. The `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` section start with `+=` , is that OK? or must the first line start with `:=` ?

Thanks.

Here is my main 'Android.mk' file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := app
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--build-id
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=

    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\.Application.mk.swp \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\Application.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\ip\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\ip\ip.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\ipd\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\ipn\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\core.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\descriptor.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\io.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\os\linux_usbfs.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\os\threads_posix.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\sync.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_orig\__Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\core.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\core_original.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\descriptor.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\descriptor_original.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\hotplug.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\hotplug_original.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\io.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\io_original.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\libusb-1.0.def \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\libusb-1.0.rc \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\Makefile.am \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\android_netlink.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\android_usbfs.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\darwin_usb.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\linux_netlink.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\linux_udev.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\linux_usbfs.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\netbsd_usb.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\openbsd_usb.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\poll_posix.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\poll_posix_original.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\poll_windows.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\threads_posix.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\threads_windows.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\wince_usb.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\os\windows_usb.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\strerror.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\sync.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\libusb_saki4510t\libusb\sync_original.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\nativeinterface\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\nativeinterface\native.c \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\Android.mk \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\libDropboxSync.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\libipandroidapp.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\libopentok.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\librs.androidappsdk_ipd.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\librs.androidappsdk_ipn.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\librs.androidappsdk_rgb2yuv.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi\libusbandroidapp.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\libDropboxSync.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\libipandroidapp.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\libopentok.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\librs.androidappsdk_ipd.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\librs.androidappsdk_ipn.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\librs.androidappsdk_rgb2yuv.so \
    D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni\prebuilt\armeabi-v7a\libusbandroidapp.so \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\main\jni

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += D:\AndroidProjects\AndroidApp\SDK\src\release\jni

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to use `/` in **.mk** files as path separators. This will be of real help if you once want to use this project on Linux.

In your case, `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` are probably irrelevant, because there are no C files in your **jni** directory.

You should clean up the *'main'* **jni/Android.mk** file. You could use (`include`) the smaller **.mk** files in the subdirectories, on assumption that they are correct. For example, I hope that **libusb/Android.mk** is not too far from the [public version on GitHub](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/android/jni/Android.mk) and does not compile the Windows-specific sources, e.g. **wince_usb.c**.

This would be a reasonable first iteration:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := app
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := native

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/ip/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/nativeinterface/Android.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/libusb_saki4510t/Android.mk
```

I cannot tell if you need the prebuilt libraries like **libDropboxSync.so** and others, but they are listed in **jni/prebuilt/Android.mk**.

Comment: OK I will change the \ to /. You said that the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES are probably irrelevant because there are no C files in my jni directory. But I do have C files in the jni directory, look at my first post, right at the beginning at lines 3 & 4 I wrote the full path of 'ip.c' and 'native.c', both of them locate inside the jni folder.

Comment: **ip.c** is covered by `$(LOCAL_PATH)/ip/Android.mk`, isn't it? And **native.c** has another **Android.mk** next to it, which I also `include`.

Comment: I don't know, I'm still a little confused about the format of this file and what need and what doesn't need to be there. What is the different between LOCAL_SRC_FILES and LOCAL_C_INCLUDES ? why the first one is not enough?

Comment: You can learn about [android.mk](http://android.mk/), but in a nutshell, LOCAL_SRC_FILES lists the c and cpp files that must be compiled (relative to LOCAL_PATH), while LOCAL_C_INCLUDES lists *directories* that contain the headers necessary to compile them. Unlike LOCAL_SRC_FILES, LOCAL_C_INCLUDES don't depend on LOCAL_PATH.